# C# windows media player and wmplib

Tags: c#

I have a C# app that loads videos from YouTube. Everything works fine, on my computer, but when I open the same file on another computer, I get the error as shown in the image.

I have verified the wmplib file is already found in the release folder.

**Does anyone know what may be causing this problem?**

[image]

Comment: You're missing the 'Interop.WMPLib' reference to run your application. Consider packaging it with your installer.

Answer (score 1):

This error means either the Interop.WMPLib.dll file is missing, or one of its dependencies is missing.

First, ensure Interop.WMPLib.dll is in the same folder as your executable.

If it is, that means one of the dependencies is missing. To find out which dependency is missing, use the [.NET framework's Assembly Binding Log Viewer tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It will tell you which dependency failed to load.